# What is the life expectancy or which component is expected to fail first?

Tags: hardware

This is a theoretical question regarding quality of modern hardware. I got a RPi but I'm not really worried about it breaking but the concept of having all components of a PC on a single board made me wonder if it's a good idea for standard PCs and Notebooks. I imagine cost would be an advantage. Maybe there's also a speed advantage having CPU, RAM and SSD soldered to the motherboard? You can't upgrade the hardware but most people do the same stuff on their PCs they did 10 years ago like surfing, office apps, watching movies and the only reason they buy new PCs is because their OS is bogged down (the average user doesn't install/reinstall a OS) and they're told to by the industry and advertising and usually NOT because their PCs break.

THE downside is that if one component breaks you gotta get a new motherboard. But that leads me to the question how long the RPi or a computer with modern components will actually last. I mean SSDs have the life expectancy of HDDs now and with the RPi having no moving parts I could imagine it going strong for much longer than 3-5 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

talking about computers in general is offtopic here.

regarding the RPi, it's most likely your power supply will send a smoke signal before anything else breaks. however, if you're talking about components attached to the board, the first candidate is the power capacitor, it is heavy and bulky, but has small soldering pads and is very likely to just fall of the board.

[image]

Comment: I would add that heat can kill the processor itself.